# Can GridDB handle GeoJSON data types?

Tags: griddb

I’d like to create an application using GridDB and a visualization of crime events on an interactive map. I have not seen anything in the docs about GeoJSON or any other geographic type data types.

I'm unsure which data type to store a GeoJSON point which has a syntax like `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.8061676,38.8250008,1.58]}`

Comment: Sad news - GridDB primarily focuses on key-value pairs and time-series data, and it doesn't natively support spatial or geospatial data types, including GeoJSON so you might need to handle the spatial aspects in your application logic  instead.